# FB.canvas and HTTPS

Tags: java, facebook, sdk, https

I'm trying to make a Facebook canvas/iframe page. I have loaded the JS SDK via HTTPs and all is fine, however when I run 'FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(91);' it breaks my HTTPS as it calls an http:// page. Thoughts on how I can fix this? My code is below

```
    <script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : '253039801382378',
    status : true, 
    cookie : true, 
    xfbml  : true, 
    channelUrl : 'https://xxx.xx.xx',  ** changed for client security
    oauth  : true 
  });
  FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(91);
</script>
```

### EDIT

Removing the channel url didnt work... Here is my full code block.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : '253039801382378',
    status : true, 
    cookie : true, 
    xfbml  : true,  
    oauth  : true 
  });
  FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(91);
</script>
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this just worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212016/facebook-javascript-sdk-over-https-loading-non-secure-items

Answer (score 0):

Remove the channelUrl attribute from there and everything should work fine. The SDSK will detect the URL automatically.

Comment: Didnt work, getting the following us error - The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/canvas_proxy.php?version=3#behavior=p&method=setSize&params=%7B%22height%22%3A1271%2C%22width%22%3A2076%2C%22frame%22%3A%22iframe_canvas%22%7D.