# Facebook and https adding <div id="fb-root" and the file is unsecure?

Tags: facebook, https

anyone notice the  will cause your https:// to be unsecure??

When i directly point the browser to https://.../myfb_app/ the file isn't parse as secure if i have the 
`<div id="fb-root"></div>` 
somewhere in the file.

but when i remove 
`<div id="fb-root"></div>`
, the whole file does parse as secure.

What is the cause and how can i fix this?
Any suggestions??
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should answer your question: [Facebook JavaScript SDK over HTTPS loading non-secure items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212016/facebook-javascript-sdk-over-https-loading-non-secure-items/7181955#7181955).

In short, add `FB._https = true;` before `FB.init` to force Facebook load files over secure connection.