# Blocked a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin

Tags: javascript, facebook, http, https

Suddenly starts to give this error :

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com" from
>   accessing a frame with origin "http://*****.com". The frame requesting
>   access set "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame being
>   accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to
>   allow access.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook: Unsafe JavaScript issue (document.domain values should be same)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892556/facebook-unsafe-javascript-issue-document-domain-values-should-be-same) OR [Facebook Login API HTTPS Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888095/facebook-login-api-https-issue) OR [Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access a frame when using secure browsing on Facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167371/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-a-frame-when-using-secure-browsing-on-facebo).

Comment: Utterly valuable question instead, because it's the one that pops up when you insert the specifi error string in Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience it means you are running the iFrame somewhere that facebook can't access, like your local computer. Facebook trys to scan your page when your iFrame comes up. If your page is public, you wont get that error and the iFrame/facebook like plugin should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have an iFrame from Facebook on your site. Some of the code on Facebook's end is trying to update your page. Your browser is blocking this behavior because the iFrame and your site are on different pages. The only way to get rid of this error is to get rid of the iFrame (unless you're friends with someone at Facebook).