# Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin ... from accessing a frame with origin

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, same-origin-policy

I've made a component for an SAP solution (whatever) that is embedded into a report through an iframe. After I deployed the report on an SAP plateform (BO), I got this error (on Chrome, but does not work on IE or FF either):

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://support.domain.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://support.domain.com". The frame requesting access set "document.domain" to "domain.com", but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.
```

The iframe is embedded into my component so it's suppose to run on the same domain with same port than report.

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308330/blocked-a-frame-with-origin-http-static-ak-facebook-com-from-accessing-a-fra) on SO and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892556/facebook-unsafe-javascript-issue-document-domain-values-should-be-same), but it does not really helped me to understand what I need to do.

Is there a way to get rid of this, or at least work around this ?
Thanks :).

**EDIT:**

Host Page URL : http://support.domain.com/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?sIDType=CUID&iDocID=AbmffWLjCAlFsLj14TjuDWg

URL of the file calling a property on the iframe (and generating the error) : http://support.domain.com/BOE/OpenDocument/1411281523/zenwebclient/zen/mimes/sdk_include/com.domain.ds.extension/res/cmp/js/component.js

URL of the frame :
http://support.domain.com/BOE/OpenDocument/1411281523/zenwebclient/zen/mimes/sdk_include/com.domain.ds.extension/res/cmp/js/map/js/map.html

The iframe embed itself some script tag, I can see everything loading fine in the Network tag of the console.

Maybe it can help.

**EDIT 2  :**

I just realized SAP report is itself embedded into an iframe. That means my iframe is within an iframe, that might be the issue. Still, when lauching the report from Eclipse, everything is working.

Comment: use `sandbox="allow-same-origin"` on your iframe, if on the same domain.

Comment: The domain and the port and the method (`http` vs. `https`) have to be **exactly** the same.

Comment: Ok I'll try sandbox property. I've added URL in my post.

Comment: and the host page url?

Comment: I've jut tried sandbox="allow-same-origin", it does not work. The same error still triggers

Comment: possible duplicate of [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: @Marco Bonelli I indeed first checked your post before posting mine, but the problem is not the same because my iframe is "technically" on the same domain as my top page. Maybe my title is not enough explicit.

Comment: @SecularKid man, I read your answer and I can assure you that these are **different** domains, for the rule I specified in my linked answer. If you have subdimain.domain.com and domain.com they are indeed different domains because the hostname, as you can see, is different.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Ok I get it, I've been mislead on term "subdomain", like explained here https://razyr.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202651353--Subdomains-vs-Host-Names- . I though that the domain was like toto.com, and in bob.toto.com, bob was the subdomain of toto (which it is technically), and so belongs to the same domain as toto.com

Comment: Still, browsers allowed me to rewrite support.domain.com to domain.com on my iframe side without moaning. So I'm kinda lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've finally found a solution.

The top of my iframe had a *domain.location* set to `domain.com` and my iframe a *domain.location* set to `support.domain.com`.

Event though I still think that both belong to the same domain, browsers don't like it it seems so.

Re-setting the *domain.location* did the work.

To answer the ones asking about how to re-set `location.domain`, here is the snippet of code my team used to use. This is quite old (2y ago), not really optimized and we do not use it anymore, but I guess it's worth sharing.
Basically, what we were doing is load the `iframe` with passing it top domain in the URL parameters.

```
var topDomain = (function handleDomain(parameters) {
        if (typeof parameters === "undefined") {
            return;
        }
        parameters = parameters.split("&");
        var parameter  = [],
            domain;
        for (var i = 0; i<parameters.length; ++i) {
            parameter.push(parameters[i]);
        }
        for (var j = 0; j<parameter.length; ++j) {
            if (parameter[j].indexOf("domain") > -1) {
                domain = parameter[j];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (typeof domain !== "undefined") {
            domain = domain.split("=");
            return domain[1];
        }
        return; 
    })(window.location.search),
    domain = document.domain;

if (domain.indexOf(topDomain) > -1 && domain !== topDomain) {
    document.domain = topDomain;
}
```

Comment: How do you reset the `domain.location`?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is no longer valid:

> Document.domain  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain
> Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

The current solution would be to use message exchanges. See samples on:
The solution is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage