# Facebook loading an asset over HTTP when browsing in HTTPS

Tags: https, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

I've done a lot of googling and have not found an answer to this problem.

I've followed the facebook docs for implementing the Facebook JS SDK. Here's the code snippet on my page

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId  : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            status : true, // check login status
            cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the //session
            xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
            oauth :true // Enable oauth 2.0
        });
        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(); //set size according to iframe content size
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));

</script>
```

This works pretty well, except for one file: **http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/canvas_proxy.php**

**all.js** loads via HTTPS just fine. But Facebook still loads in canvas_proxy.php via regular HTTP:

http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/canvas_proxy.php?version=3#behavior=p&method=setSize&params=%7B%22height%22%3A714%2C%22width%22%3A1100%2C%22frame%22%3A%22iframe_canvas%22%7D

Why is this? I seem to be doing everything right. HTTPS users get a security warning thrown when they visit my page because of that URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting FB._https = true, before the FB.init call.  This will take care of canvas_proxy.php.

Solution originally detailed in [Facebook JavaScript SDK over HTTPS loading non-secure items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212016/facebook-javascript-sdk-over-https-loading-non-secure-items)

Comment: I tried that, and it still loads via HTTP unfortunately. I tried clearing my cache/cookies in case that was a cached request -- still loads HTTP. Thank you, though.