# Do not receive a response from FBAS.init

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api, facebook-actionscript-api

It was working till Thursday of last week, but I'm wondering if something changed cause the code has been the same since then.

I pass the following JSON information to the FBAS.init call from my app in facebook

```
{"oauth":true,"appId":"MYAPPID"}
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
//We call Facebook API init call like so:   
trace("init");
Facebook.init(_appKey, _fbInitResponse);


//Here's our callback
protected function _fbInitResponse(success:Object, fail:Object):void
{
    trace("fbInitResponse: success = " + success);

    // User logged in successfully
    if (success) 
    {
        trace("\t session recieved!");
        _session = success;
        dispatchEvent(new Event(FacebookEvent.INIT));
    } 
    else 
    {
        trace("ERROR: " + fail);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to post some more code.

Answer (score 1):

**Actually:** It looks like a bug with Facebook not redirecting to the Secure Canvas URL properly. The hack below is a short-term work-around, but this looks like a bug on Facebooks end.

Ran into the same problem as you. Was a mismatch when a user was using https to access the Facebook app, but the app page was being served in http.

A Facebook auth change has been propagating to users since March.
I assume this was the change to cause the bustage:
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#enhanced-auth-dialog

The tip found in this answer helped me:
[Facebook JavaScript SDK over HTTPS loading non-secure items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212016/facebook-javascript-sdk-over-https-loading-non-secure-items)

I put the: `FB._https = (window.location.protocol == "https:");`

I put it right after the fb-root div in a script element. Very hacky.