# Facebook Javascript SDK produces SSL error

Tags: javascript, facebook, ssl

I have a mobile webapp that uses the JavaScript Facebook-SDK. The webapp runs over HTTP. To load an initialize the SDK i've used the HowTo from [JavaScript Facebook-SDK How-To](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

Now the problem is, that I sometimes get the warning "Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occured and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." Furthermore there is a URL called "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?..."

This problem only occurs sometimes and results in an Alert-Box on my iPhone that says "[App-Name] could not be opened because it could not establish a secure connection to the server.", when i launch the webapp from the home screen.

Does anybody know why I get this error?

For reference my code to load and initialize the SDK.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                            FB._https = false;
                            FB.init({
                              appId      : '[my app id]', // App ID
                              status     : true, // check login status
                              cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                              xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
                            });
                            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', handleStatusChange);
                          };

                          // Load the SDK Asynchronously
                          (function(d){
                             var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                             js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                             ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
                           }(document));
```

Comment: A simple search here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5212016/910325

Comment: I've seen this post before but adding FB._https = true; or FB._https = false; has no effect. The error still occurs.

Comment: you can try to force the https protocol by replacing:      

 `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";` with
         
 `js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";`

Comment: Replacing with {js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";} has unfortunately no effect too. The error is still there.

Comment: I think I know what your problem is... if you are working from your own machine and set the URL in the app settings to `localhost` - that won't work. Facebook won't be able to translate `localhost` to where you are. you have to put a real URL.
If no one else but you can access the URL - then it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have u mentioned a correct url in the app settings in FB, where it says once you have to put the http url next as https ?

Comment: The "Mobile Site URL" and the "Site URL" is set to "http://localhost:8080/[My App URI]" or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I meant, did you mention canvas URL as well as secure canvas URL properly in fb app settings.