# Facebook profile pic coming up as Http: on secure website expected Https:

Tags: facebook, ssl, https, profile, image

On my Drupal 7 Website when users login with Facebook it pulls an insecure image

http:// profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/211260_100002498550684_1807914074_s.jpg

I am using Drupal For Facebook

I've followed instructions here

[Facebook JavaScript SDK over HTTPS loading non-secure items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212016/facebook-javascript-sdk-over-https-loading-non-secure-items)

Maybe it is outdated, what is the current fix for this?

Also oddly, When I login with my Facebook account it does not have the problem

https:// fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/211648_100004825298386_474362609_s.jpg

How do I make the profile pics secure no matter what? Thank your for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily have the Graph API return the SSL URL for a user picture by appending the parameter `return_ssl_resources=1` – see Mark’s picture, requested in the secure version:

https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?return_ssl_resources=1

Comment: That doesn't work, I added the following code to example.php
`<?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture?return_ssl_resources=1">`

Comment: Define _“that doesn’t work”_ please – since when you click the link I posted, you should be able to clearly see that it _does work._

Comment: I meant I don't know where the code goes for me, I can't figure it out. Drupal For Facebook must have this code hidden or maybe I'm suppose to put it in the facebook sdk js library. I don't know. ?return_ssl_resources=1 does work I just cant get it to work for me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This was a great response. The links that are returned from the graph link with the `return_ssl_resource` parameter set to 1 differ slightly from the non-ssl links.

**https**
`https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/372719_100002538572418_1473050437_q.jpg`

**http**
`http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/372719_100002538572418_1473050437_q.jpg`

You can updated existing http links to use ssl by replacing `http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net` with `https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net`

Answer (score 1):

So upon further review I came to realize that my Facebook profile was the only one having problems on my website with my profile picture staying unsecured after logging in with Facebook.

Upon digging deeper I realized when I logged into www.facebook.com directly my connection was by default unsecured as well.

I went into Account Setting and the Security tab and it said something about Secure browsing being in migration. I changed Secure Browsing to enabled and voila!

Everything is working perfectly.

I'm still wanting to implement this

```
str_replace('http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net','https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net',$user['pic_square']);
```

So just in case someone it stuck in old school unsecured browsing it replaces the link but I don't even know how to do this or where the code goes but I will save that for another day.