# Login with Facebook javascript SDK does work on certains browsers cause of SSL

Tags: javascript, facebook, ssl, facebook-javascript-sdk

**The context**

- a facebook web app
- facebook SDK 2.5 loaded asynchronously
- login with facebook feature
- into Angular 1.5 application
- localhost and ssl domains to test
- ssl domains on production
- all above domains are added to *Valid OAuth redirect URIs* field on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/xxxx/settings/advanced/

**The issue**

I followed recommendations to implement facebook login. That appeared to work well with my machine (linux). Then a co-worker told me it was not working on his own (Mac).

Errors were in red facebook popup something like:

- Please login (not the form, but a text to tell you should log to facebook)
- The uri is not a part of Valid OAuth redirect URIs list

And after few more test on differents configurations the facebook login work

- Linux with Chrome: ok
- Linux with Firefox: ok
- Linux with Opera: not working
- certains Mac with Chrome: ok
- certains Mac with Chrome: not working
- certains Mac with Firefox: ok
- certains Mac with Firefox: not working
- certains Mac with Safari: ok
- certains Mac with Safari: not working
- Windows with Chrome: not working
- Windows with Firefox: not working
- Windows with Internet Explorer: ok

... so finally quite random.

**the clue**

Using developer tools on Linux/Opera I saw the `redirect_uri` was targeting `http://test.my-domain.com` instead of `https://test.my-domain.com`

**solution 1**

Then I tried this:

`window.FB._https = true;
window.FB.init( ... );`

from [Facebook JavaScript SDK over HTTPS loading non-secure items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212016/facebook-javascript-sdk-over-https-loading-non-secure-items)

it didn't changed anything.

**solution 2**

I added non ssl version of my domains to facebook app configuration page. To *Valid OAuth redirect URIs* field in fact.

this one worked well.

**Questions**

As it is unclear in documentation. And as you can make distinction between `http`and `https` domains I'm wondering:

- if it is the way it should be done?
- and is it something to do with: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/02/Update-on-Transition-to-SHA-2/ ?

Comment: Your domain use https? Can you test it with ssllabs.com ?

Comment: Yes my domain use https. Just did the check. Quite long 2 / 3 mins. This gave me two lines. With an IP and a grade. Both grades are A.

Comment: And about the list of browsers supported (in the same page) ?

Comment: in *Handshake Simulation* part, all lines are black TLS 1.0 or green TLS 1.2. Except one version of IE which is red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few more try. The only way to make it works seems to be this:

> I added non ssl version of my domains to facebook app configuration page. To Valid OAuth redirect URIs field in fact.